# Hec-Ras 6.0 error creating terrain (Step 1 Translating to GeoTIFF)

Tags: hec-ras

I want to create a terrain in RAS Mapper (right click 'Terrains' -> 'Create a new RAS Terrain'). Following error occure:

```
Computation Task                                                                 |   hh:mm:ss
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Importing 1 of 1: dgm_sa_hec.asc -> Terrain.dgm_sa_hec.tif
Step 1 of 4: Translating to GeoTiff with SRS...
ERROR 1: missing [

ERROR 1: Failed to process SRS definition: ESRI::*path*\DGM\dgm_sa_hec.prj
Step 1 of 4: Translating to GeoTiff with SRS...                                  |          0
Error creating Terrain: *path*HecRas\Terrain\Terrain.dgm_sa_hec.tif: No such file or directory
Cleaning up files...
```

I already used an ASCII File and a TIFF but both doesn't work. There are no special characters in the path. The Terrain folder is created automaticly.

Does anyone have experience with a similar problem?
Using hec-ras 6.0 Beta2

Comment: I guess there is a problem with the '*path*'. In 5.0.7 any special character made the creation procedure to fail. I think those routines are quite old and not updated

Comment: That was also my first thought. But i checked the path and there are not special character in there.

Comment: Then it could be the data type. I have experienced problems with that, but I do not remember which ones do not work. Anyway, the clue is in the error messages. Doesn't `Terrain.dgm_sa_hec.tif`has two dots? Does SRS file a proper format and projecttion type?

Comment: I agree this was not a problem in HEC-RAS 5. In the past exporting GeoTIFF files from Civil 3D for HEC-RAS 6, I was able to work around this by trying Create New RAS Terrain a second time and selecting one of the intermediate TIF files in the HEC-RAS Terrain sub-folder. But that's not working for me with the GeoTIFF I have from QGIS. Still no answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same errors importing two layers, an elevation model and a survey. I found that the elevation model alone would import with no problem. In the New Terrain Layer dialog box, where the layers are added, I saw that the survey layer had no projection defined. This had not been a problem in HEC RAS 5.0.x, but it was a problem in 6.0. I defined the projection in GIS and exported the raster as .tif, and RAS imported the two layers to a single terrain with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error recently, maybe it's the same thing. I'm a little bit late, but I hope it helps someone that encounters this problem in the future. I was able to add the terrain after setting the file to the CRS I wanted in QGIS. Even if your terrain is already in the given CRS, it seems like HEC-RAS wasn't able to recognize it as a regular projection, but instead as a "custom" one.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is on pages 79-82 of the HEC-RAS Guides and Tutorials document (v6.4.1), which you can download from the HEC website. The problem stems from RAS Mapper not recognizing the SRS data stored in your geoTIFF, but the guide provides a workaround to this issue.

Here's the link to download the Guide as a PDF:

https://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-ras/documentation/HEC-RAS%20Guides%20and%20Tutorials-v6.4.1.pdf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).